# Getting Value in Subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, mysql-error-1064

I donot want **r.reguser_id as test** column in results, And if i remove this Column from Select statement then i am having problem in **WHERE  bu.business_id = r.reguser_id** and got an error of **More then 1 row Returns.**

```
SELECT r.reguser_name ,  r.reguser_id as test,

(Select r.reguser_id as c, GROUP_CONCAT(i.industry_name) as Industry

From reguser r inner JOIN business_industry bu ON r.reguser_id = bu.business_id  join industry i ON bu.industry_id = i.industry_id

WHERE  bu.business_id = test

GROUP BY bu.business_id
) as indus

FROM reguser r
```

Kindly tell me how can i resolve this issue ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT r.reguser_name ,  r.reguser_id,

(Select r1.reguser_id as c, GROUP_CONCAT(i.industry_name) as Industry

From reguser r1 inner JOIN business_industry bu ON r1.reguser_id = bu.business_id  join industry i ON bu.industry_id = i.industry_id

WHERE  bu.business_id = r.reguser_id

GROUP BY bu.business_id
) as indus

FROM reguser r
```

Don't use the same alliases for main table and table in subquery. It's really bad practice

Comment: Yes, Changing the r to r1 solves my problem, Perfect Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.user_name FROM
(SELECT r.reguser_name as user_name,  r.reguser_id as test,

(Select r.reguser_id as c, GROUP_CONCAT(i.industry_name) as Industry

From reguser r inner JOIN business_industry bu ON r.reguser_id = bu.business_id  join     industry i ON bu.industry_id = i.industry_id

WHERE  bu.business_id = test

GROUP BY bu.business_id
) as indus

FROM reguser r)t1
WHERE t1.user_name IS NOT NULL
```

i think you need to have some sort of where clause if you are using sql developer when querying  this way, i.e, giving an alias to a select query. Hope this helps..